# How can I install clang 3.9 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, clang

Our old server runs Ubuntu 12.04 and has clang 3.4 version.
We are now checking Ubuntu 16.04.
From what I see when I try `apt-get install clang` - the possible version to install are 3.5 to 3.9.

I want to be able to test the new version of clang on our old server before we making the upgrade. How can I install the new version (3.9) on ubuntu 12.04?
I can't find it using `apt-get install`.

Another input that probably relevant to my issue is I'm working offline.

Comment: You won't be able you install/download it from Internet?

Comment: You said the possible version to install are `3.5 to 3.9` and then said in second paragraph `can't find it using apt-get install`! I'm confused. Will you edit the question to clear the matter

Comment: On 16.04 I can find only 3.5 to 3.9. On 12.04 I can find up until 3.4.

Comment: I wrote an answer. Check if that works

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can install clang 3.9 on Ubuntu 12.04.

1 - You need to add these repository to your `sources.list` file.

```
deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty main
# 3.8 
deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.8 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.8 main
# 3.9 
deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9 main
```

2- Then you need to add `ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` ppa. Because it provides updated `libstdc++` required by clang 3.9

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

3 - Now update the repository index

```
sudo apt-get update
```

4 - You should now be able to install clang 3.9

```
sudo apt-get install clang-3.9
```

<sup>Source: http://apt.llvm.org/</sup>

---

If you need help installing package without Internet, use the solutions from this question

- [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be to download all the packages to the 16.04 installation first.  Then copy them to a USB drive or something to transport them over to the 12.04 server.  Then install all packages to the 12.04 server.

To download `clang` and all of its dependencies, run the following command from a terminal window.  (Might want to make a separate folder to download to):

*Note:  From the default 16.04 repositories that I have, it only downloaded clang 3.8.*

```
apt download $(apt-rdepends clang|grep -v "^ ")
```

The above command will download all files to the folder you are presently in on the system.